# How to get the same list of folder structure which are available in google drive UI

Tags: google-drive-api

while using the google driver api it returns the entire list of files and folder. I need to get the same list of directories which are currently available in my account

For example in Google drive currently am having the folders like
A
B->c
D

with the API if i tried to get the file am getting the entire files
as like 
A
B
c
D

But by scenario is I need to get the same set of file list that are currently available in the G drive

Usability of the above scenario:
Using this am trying to create the same UI in client side so that I can create and delete and sync file locally.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: problem resolved, Any way thanks for your interest